# Show that $T(X) =\{f\in A(S)|f(X)\subset X\}$ is a subgroup of $A(S)$ if X is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $S$ is a nonempty set and $X\subset S$, Show that $T(X)=\{f\in A(S)|f(X)\subset X\}$ is a subgroup of $A(S)$ if X is *finite*. Note: $A(S)$ is called "symmetric group". It's actually a collection of all bijective mappings from $S$ into itself equipped with the operation of composition between functions.

Here is my proof:

> First show that $f$ is bijective from $X$ into itself.
>   
> For $\forall x,x' \in X$, $f(x) \neq f(x')$, therefore it's one to one.
>   
> If there are $n$ elements in $X$, then there are $n$ representations in $f(X)$. And since $f$ is one to one, these representations are distinct, or there are $n$ elements in $f(X)$. And each element in $f(X)$ is in $X$. These statements are true if and only if $f(X)=X$, therefore $f$ is onto.
>
> Then we prove that $T(X)$ is a subgroup. 
>   
> Since $f$ is bijective from $X$ into itself, there exists an $f^{-1}$ that is bijective and is from $X$ into itself. And the composition $fg$ is bijective and is from $X$ into itself.
>
> Therefore, $T(X)$ is a subgroup for $A(S)$.

But wait, does this proof involve the fact that $X$ is finite? I think maybe the assumption that "there are n elements in $X$" will answer this question. But what if $X$ is infinite? Is the statement still valid then? If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $f$ is function from $S$ to $S$, In your proof you actually showed that restriction of such $f$ to $X$ is forms a group. (I may misunderstand your intention, I want it to be clear)

Now, let $f,g\in T(x)$ ;

we need to show that $f^{-1}g\in T(X)$ to say that $T(X)\leq A(S)$.

We know that $f(X)\subseteq X$ but since $f$ is one to one $|f(X)|=|X|\implies f(X)=X$.

Thus, $f^{-1}(X)=X$ so $f^{-1}g(X)=f^{-1}(X)=X\implies f^{-1}g\in T(X)$ we are done.

When $X$ is infinite above statement need not to be true since $f(X)$ can be proper subset of $X$ even if it is one to one then $f^{-1}(X)\subsetneq X$ so it fails to be subgroup.

Comment: "restriction of such f to X is forms a group" That's what you have to do when you want to prove that T(X) is a subgroup. "we need to show that f−1g∈T(X) to say that T(X)≤A(S)", but can you explain that to me? My intention: though I've prove that T(X) is a subgroup, however I don't think I've use the fact that X is finite. Maybe the phrase" if there exist n elements" can give a hint on that.

Comment: If $H$ is a nonempty set of $G$ and $h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
. think of $\sigma=(1,2)(3,4)$ and $\tau=(3,4)$ then $\sigma,\tau \in S_4$ and their restriction to set $\{1,2\}$ are $(1,2)$ and $(1)$ and forms a group. But in $S_4$, $\{\sigma,\tau\}$ is not a group. finiteness of $X$ force $f(X)\subset X\implies X=f(X)$ otherwise you can not conclude this.

Comment: According to what I've learned so far, if H is finite, then we need to check if H is closed under multiplication when showing that H is a subgroup. But your method doesn't seem familiar or obvious to me

Comment: @pxc3110: this is not my method of corse, there are many equivalent way to show it. Please check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup and read the part under the title Basic properties of subgroups.

Comment: Can you explain this to me: When X is infinite then f(X) can be proper subset of X even if it is one to one

Comment: An infinite set can be one to one embeded into itself  such that its image is proper in it. Let have an example; $F:N\to N$ by $f(n)=2n$. you can easily see that $f$ is one to one functon fron $N$ to $N$ but its image is set of all even numbers which is proper subset of $N$.